# Max value error handling, with reactive forms

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

I want to print a error message when the input value reach the max number, but i don't know what missing.

here is the form control:

```
 aidAmount: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [
      Validators.max(10000000),
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('[0-9]+'),
    ]),
```

And here is the html side:

```
<td>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Maximum aid amount</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="aidAmount">
                <span matSuffix>Ft</span>
               <span *ngIf="this.calculatorForm.controls.aidAmount.errors?.max">Maximum value is 1000</span>
            </mat-form-field>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to official documents, this is the way to refer to reactive form.

```
<div *ngIf="AidAmount.errors?.['max']">
     Aid amount must be at max 100000
</div>
```